# Access origin issue on Express application

Tags: node.js, angular, express, web-applications, cors

I have created an express application with angular ui. I have following the app.js file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var userRouter = require('./routes/user');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/student', userRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next(createError(404));
});



// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I got error like this

```
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin. is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: About the frontend JavaScript that’s sending the request, where is that running? When you say “I have created an express application with angular ui”, do you mean that your frontend JavaScript code which is making the request is the frontend for that application? If so, there where is your frontend JavaScript code sending the request to? Some other external site that you don’t control?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set multiple fields at once, pass an object as the parameter. For example, 
`res.set({
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
});`

Answer (score -1):

Can you implement like this and check.

[image]

OR

If you want to work quick as of now, there is a hack code for chrome. Run this

In Windows, paste this command in run window
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Answer (score -1):

Actually this problem must be solved from the server side (API). If you are in testing locally or you are in different domain then you must allow the CORS from the API Implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CORS extension of chrome for development purpose